# Create a Statefule widget with a TextFormFiled inside

Tags: flutter

I have an application that has a lot of forms with lots of UI changes.
Everytime I add a `TextFormField` to a form, I have to add so many lines of code:

```
Widget usernameCodeTextFiled() {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: _usernameTextController,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
      onChanged: (_) => setState(() {}),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
        labelText: 'Username',
        hintText: 'Enter your username',
        errorText: _submitted
            ? usernameValidationMessage(_usernameTextController.text)
            : null,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

So I decided to create a `Stateful widget` with a `TextFormField` and its layout and use that instead of directly using `TextFormField`:

```
class TextEntry extends StatefulWidget {

//...

  @override
  State<TextEntry> createState() => _TextEntryState();
}

class _TextEntryState extends State<TextEntry> {
// ...

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: TextFormField(
        controller: _textController,
        keyboardType: _keyboardType,
        onChanged: _onChanged,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
          labelText: _labelText,
          hintText: _hintText,
          errorText: _errorMessage,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This resulted a much cleaner and more reusable code:

```
//...
TextEntry(
  textController: _usernameTextController,
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  onChanged: (_) => setState(() {}),
  labelText: 'Username',
  hintText: 'Enter your username',
  errorMessage: _submitted
      ? usernameValidationMessage(_usernameTextController.text)
      : null,
),
//...
```

The only problem I have is that form validation will not work this way. How can I enable form validation for my `TextEntry` widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define validator in textEntry like this

```
final String? Function(String?)? validator;
```

in

```
TextFormField(
 validator: validator,
)
```

You can use like this

```
 TextEntry(
validator: (value) {
                  if (value!.isEmpty) {
                       return StringProvider.pleaseEnterPass;
                   } else if (value.length < 8) {
                     return StringProvider.passwordLength;
                   }
         },
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the validation function, like `final String? Function(String?)? customValidator;` and pass it to the widget,

```
TextFormField(
  validator: customValidator,
  ...
)
```

and pass it from the parent widget like,

```
TextEntry(
  customValidator: (v) {
    ...
  }
)
```

I'd suggest to replace the `StatefulWidget` with `StatelessWidget` as you can pass on the `controller` from the parent widget, and add another parameter like `customValidator` to improve performance.

Comment: `StatefulWidget` is better than `stateful`. So upvote your answer.